# How do you skip the first line when copying csv files in command prompt?

Tags: csv, command-line

I am merging csv files all lying in the same folder. I use this format "COPY *.csv newfile.csv"  in command prompt. But i would like to know what i must add so that i can skip the first line of each csv file i am copying to the new csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for /f "skip=1 delims="` command to parse the files.

and a `more +1` command will also be useful for this.